# Determine all global variables of a module

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

How to determine all global variables of a LLVM module?

I want to modify them using a module pass.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`llvm::Module` class has `getGlobalList()` method:

```
/// Get the Module's list of global variables.
GlobalListType         &getGlobalList()             { return GlobalList; }
```

So you can do something like:

```
for (auto &Global : M->getModule()->getGlobalList()) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

In LLVM-17, `getGlobalList()` has been made a private method. The list of global variables can be accessed via iterators (both mutable and const versions are available): [global_begin()](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Module.html#a0567b31cf5caa26522fcc2e7cadc1dde) and [global_end()](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Module.html#a19b72cdd81bd792545e25466b43ac7c2). Referring to the code of [Module.h](https://llvm.org/doxygen/Module_8h_source.html) makes it quite clear. A for loop like the following will do the needful:

```
   for (auto Global = M->getModule()->global_begin();
             Global != M->getModule()->global_end();
             ++Global)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the documentation. Maybe it's worth mentioning that you also can use method `globals`:  `for (auto var : M->getModule()->globals()) { ... }`